# Homology of symplectic manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, symplectic-geometry

Could you show me some example of compact symplectic 4-manifold $M$
with the torsion in $H_{2}(M;\mathbb{Z})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus \{0\}/\sim$ where $\sim$ is the quotient by the antipodal map, with the standard Kähler structure. To get it to be compact, quotient it further by $x\mapsto 2x$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "compact manifold"

Comment: Thanks! Could you please show me any open cover of this manifold (without second quotient).

Comment: What kind of open cover do you need?